# Transmit Tcp port number

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to have two computers communicate over a local network using WCF. In order to avoid port-collision, I had planned to transmit a dynamic port number over udp since udp services can share a port easily. The problem is that whatever will be the prearranged port for the udp broadcast - it might be taken by some other application on one of the computers on the network.

So: Is there some way to overcome this, such as some port reserved for udp broadcasts (which is always `ExclusiveAddressUse = false`) for instance? Some other way?

Comment: The two solutions to this are either 1) Pick a big random number between 49152 and 65535 and hope for a low chance of collisions, or 2) Go [apply for a assigned port number](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt) from the IANA

Comment: I'm trying to use dynamic ports (49152-65535) which don't require that.

Comment: that would be option 1 I mentioned, pick a random number in that range and hope for no collisions

Comment: Do you need to use UDP broadcast because you are trying to discover the peer's IP address as well?

Comment: @jxh Not necessarily. Why?

Comment: If the peer's IP address is known, you don't need to use an ad hoc protocol to discover the listening port via UDP. You can use HTTP to communicate the listening port via a CGI script.

Comment: @jxh Thanks. Any pointers as to how I can do that? I do know how to use WCF with http, but I need a free port for that too. So what is it exactly that you mean? Any information will be appreciated.

Comment: If you control the targeted machines, then utilize or install a webserver on those machines, and configure them to allow a CGI script that you use to trigger your application.